# Using shader graphs to add an outline to a sprite of a tank. Despite following tutorials, the outline distorts the sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to add a black outline surrounding a sprite I have for a tank.

I've tried following every tutorial I could find on 2d outlines for sprites, however almost all of them were done using a previous unity version (I'm using 2021.1.3f1) and don't seem to have any of the problems I've been having.

After using Alpha subtraction on an offset copy of the sample texture (and multiplying by a color) I then try to add it back to the original sample texture. That's when things go wrong, no matter what I've tried it keeps either chopping off the right side of the sprite (I was trying to add the left outline first), or making the right side of the sprite the opposite color of what I'm putting on the left.

[image]

What I mean by "cutting off the right", those treads should be the same thickness on the right as on the left, it's like adding the outline to one side trimmed the other.
[image]

If it matters, the sprite is a PNG I got from Kenney and then modified in Krita.
For whatever reason, changing the color of the outline seems to also change how much is getting trimmed.

I've been banging my head against this for four hours now, any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Update: After following One Full Time Equivalent's suggestion below I do get an outline surrounding the entire sprite, but now it's distorting the colors at the edges of the sprite as seen here:
[image]

After replacing Add with Blend
[image]

Comment: Did you ever get a complete solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

After your subtraction node, put in an `Absolute` node, otherwise you will subtract the right edge in the alpha channel (this is exactly what you observe right now). Always be aware that you can only see half the color space and negative channels can be tricky to deal with.

Comment: Good call on the Absolute node, I can use it to prevent the trimming, however it's now distorting the colors on every edge of the sprite as seen above:

Comment: Yes, this is because `Add` is not exactly a great composition function. Try `Blend` in `Overwrite` mode and pass in the alpha channel of your edges as `Opacity`. You might need to do some preprocessing on the alpha channel (simple ramp should suffice), but try this first.

Comment: Replacing add with blend doesn't seem to change anything. Unless I'm inputting them in the wrong order?

Comment: In this case the outline is still a bit messy. Clean it with a ramp where the outline is 1 if red channel is between .9 and 1 else 0.

Comment: How do I create a ramp? It's not one of the listed node options.

Comment: For this particular case you can use a `Step` node, otherwise it's just basic math and you can easily build it yourself.